# how to load list from service using javascript

Tags: javascript

Im try to view the employee info using GetAllEmployee method from EmployeeWebService in dataset but i have a problem Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) in consol
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

```
@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">
        var dataSet = [];
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#demo').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>');
            // Load Employees
            GetAllEmployees();
            $('#example').dataTable({
                "data": dataSet,
                "columns": [
                    { "title": "Emplyee Id" },
                    { "title": "Emplyee Name" },
                    { "title": "Emplyee Salary" }
                ]
            });
        });
        function GetAllEmployees() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "EmployeeWebService.asmx/GetAllEmployees",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    var employees = response.d;//var Employees = response.d;
                    $.each(employees, function (index, employee) {

                        dataSet.push({ id: employee.Id, name: employee.Name, salary: employee.Salary });
                    });
                },
                failure: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
        }

</script>
```

}

```
<body class="dt-example">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="demo"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What does your endpoint implementation look like? (EmployeeWebService.asmx/GetAllEmployees)

Comment: public class EmployeeWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {
    List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
    public EmployeeWebService () {
        list.Add(new Employee { Id = 1, Name = "Ali", Salary = 22000 });
        list.Add(new Employee { Id = 2, Name = "Ahmed", Salary = 24000 }); 
    } 
    [WebMethod]
    public List<Employee> GetAllEmployees() {  
        return list;
    }